# Grouping fields in Hasura

Tags: graphql, hasura

I am new to GraphQL. I have a query that looks something like this

```
query X {
    x
    y
    z
    a
    b
    p
    q
```

I want the response to be like this:

```
m: {
   x
   y
   z
},
n: {
   a
   b
},
o: {
   p
   q
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can't do that. The only thing that you can change in the response structure is the name of fields. Renaming fields has a practical use: It allows you to query the same field twice with different parameters. Apart from that, GraphQL does not concern itself with restructuring of the response. Make 3 different queries or reshape the response on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you edit the schema to set `X` query's return type to an [Object Type](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#object-types-and-fields):

```
type Query {
  X: XResponse
}

type XResponse {
  m: M
  n: N
  o: O
}

type M {
  x: String!
  y: String
  z: Boolean
}

type N {
  a: [Float]
  b: String
}

type O {
  p: Int
  q: AnotherObjectType
}
```

This is a big advantage of GraphQL: your schema's types [match your business domain](https://graphql.org/learn/thinking-in-graphs/).

If you cannot modify the schema's query definition, then no, as @Herku's comment explains.